# Flask migration command is not showing error messages

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

We are using Flask with SQLAlchemy and Flask migrate. This was working fine so far but lately it has stopped showing error messages on failures. It just silently fails. I believe this started happening when we upgraded flask-migrate but I'm not 100% sure.

The issue is not that it's failing, it only fails when there's a proper reason (multiple head versions, or invalid migration file), but it does not report the error on console.

```
> flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
> echo $?
1
```

It works fine and applies migration when there's no failure:

```
> flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 34f504777ec2 -> ed96adbb2dd6, empty message
> echo $?
0
```

Versions:

```
> flask --version
Python 3.9.15
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```

```
Flask-Migrate = "^2.5.3"
```

Not sure why the error messages are not showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an old bug, it's not a problem with your application.

The most important thing you need to do is to update the `alembic.ini` file that is in your `migrations` directory. You can take the updated version [from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/blob/main/src/flask_migrate/templates/flask/alembic.ini.mako).

I think with the above all errors will be printed to the console.

In addition, you may consider upgrading Flask-Migrate to a more recent release, since the version that you are using is about 2.5 years old.